# Using max() on a list containing strings and integers

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, max

When I try to call the `max()` function on a list which contains a combination of integers and strings, it always returns a string, in Python 2.x

For example,

```
#input
li = [2, 232322, 78, 'python', 77]
max(li)

#output
'python'
```

What seems to be the logic behind this? How does Python compare a string with an integer?

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: It's raise an error in Python 3.4

Comment: If you compare a string to an int, the string is always greater (in Python 2). In Python 3, they are not longer comparable.

Comment: @cricket_007 I just want to know why a string is being returned instead of an integer. How does Python 2.7 compare a string with an integer?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi The short answer is "Because it's defined that way". There's no sensible way to always compare strings and numbers, so it just makes a consistent (but meaningless) decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In python2, strings and numbers compare in arbitrary but consistent order.

See [Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result

In python3, this raises a type error.

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Comment: How does Python 2.7 compare a string with an integer? I mean, is there a logic behind this or is it something that is just defined?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi It's arbitrary

Comment: @Daenyth - in cPython not totally arbitrary, a bit further down in the doc you linked: _**CPython implementation detail:** Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names_ - so strings come before ints because `'str' > 'int'`

Comment: @mata It's not arbitrary at runtime, the decision of how they are sorted when they can't be sorted is arbitrary - in this case it's str > int but that's not required - as implied by the bit you quoted saying `implementation detail`

Comment: It's not arbitrary in cPython: they are sorted first by type-name, then sort-order within that type. So `sorted( ['a',1,'1','c',2,0,'e','d',3,'b','2','0',9e99, 9e-99] ) =
[0, 9e-99, 1, 2, 3, 9e+99, '0', '1', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`. Numeric first, then string. Looks very deterministic to me. (Does PyPy follow this?)

Comment: @smci I never said it wasn't deterministic - deciding that types sort by type name is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

The comparision between strings and numbers is undefined. It depends on the version of python. Strings are either always larger than any number or lower.

The [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) states, that in CPython different objects are compared after their type name, if no other comparision is defined.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x
The max() and min() functions first internally sort the list, resulting in a list similar to the output of list.sort() and then outputs the last (max) and first(min) item of the list-

```
>>> li = [2, 232322, 78, 'python', 77]
>>> max(li)
'python'
>>> min(li)
2
```

As you can see below if you sort the list the first and last item in the list are the result produce by min and max functions

```
>>> li = [2, 232322, 78, 'python', 77]
>>> li.sort()
>>> print li
[2, 77, 78, 232322, 'python']
```

Comment: Are you sure it "first internally sort[s] the list"? This would be very inefficient, and looking at the source code it seems to just do the expected sequential traversal looking for the smallest or largest entry.